# convert code to functions in python

Tags: python-3.x, function, tkinter

Hi I am running into problems making a rate function from an existing function in python 3.6 I keep getting errors `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'StringVar'` or `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'Tag'`. I have normally had no problems doing this sort of thing.

Here is the first function.

```
def results():
    if running:
        cur1 = listbox1.get('active')
        cur2 = listbox2.get('active')

        t = datetime.utcnow()  
        url1  = "http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/" + "?Amount=" + amountex + "&From=" + cur1 + "&To=" + cur2
        url2 = "http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/" + "?Amount=" + amountex + "&From=" + cur2 + "&To=" + cur1


        html_code1 = requests.get(url1).text
        html_code2 = requests.get(url2).text

        soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html_code1, 'html.parser')
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html_code2, 'html.parser')

        rate1 = soup1.find('span', {'class', 'uccResultAmount'})
        rate2 = soup2.find('span', {'class', 'uccResultAmount'})

        lblfrmex_text.set(rate2.contents[0])
        lbltoex_text.set(rate1.contents[0])
        lbldatetime_text.set(t)
#Then do a whole bunch of calculations.
```

And this is what I am trying.

```
def getrates(curA, curB):
        url1  = "http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/" + "?Amount=" + amountex + "&From=" + curA + "&To=" + curB
        url2 = "http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/" + "?Amount=" + amountex + "&From=" + curB + "&To=" + curA

        html_code1 = requests.get(url1).text
        html_code2 = requests.get(url2).text

        soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html_code1, 'html.parser')
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html_code2, 'html.parser')

        rate1 = soup1.find('span', {'class', 'uccResultAmount'})
        rate2 = soup2.find('span', {'class', 'uccResultAmount'})

        lblfrmex_text.set(rate2.contents[0])
        lbltoex_text.set(rate1.contents[0])
        return lblfrmex_text, lbltoex_text

def results():
    if running:
        cur1 = listbox1.get('active')
        cur2 = listbox2.get('active')

        t = datetime.utcnow()  
        lbldatetime_text.set(t)

#Get cur1/cur2 exrates

        var1 = getrates(cur1, cur2)
        var2 = (var1[0])
        var3 = (var1[0])
        rate1contents = float(var2)
        rate2contents = float(var3)
        print (rate1contents)
```

I know im almost there but i cant seem to see where i am going wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: added
        
        a = float (rate1.contents[0])
        b = float (rate2.contents[0])

Comment: seems to fine now

Comment: also why wouldnt a global variable be showing up in the variable explorer

Comment: Have you found a solution to this question? If so, please can you add an answer and select it as accepted. If not, can you please provide an MCVE to allow us to troubleshoot the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: will review your request once I have proper net access